# Fast Walsh–Hadamard transform generalization for non-power-of-two orders?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, signal-processing

I have to process vectors through a [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order N.

If N is a power of 2, I can use the [Fast Walsh–Hadamard transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform); but if N is not a power of two (for instance, N=12),  it is not possible, however i would like to avoid the direct matrix product.

**Is there any generalization of the Fast Walsh–Hadamard transform for `N ≠ 2^k`?** Thanks.

Comment: The Fast Walsh-Hadamard Transform is based on the recursive block structure of Hadamard matrices of order $2^k$ as $$H_{2^k} = \left[\begin{matrix} H_{2^{k-1}} & H_{2^{k-1}}\\ H_{2^{k-1}} & -H_{2^{k-1}}\end{matrix}\right].$$ When the order is not a power of $2$, such a block structure would _at best_ recurse a few times, and then you are still left with a (smaller) matrix-vector product to compute.  The saving grace is, of course, that no _multiplications_ need be used; additions and subtractions suffice to compute the matrix-vector product.

Comment: @Dilip: so, given a kernel of transform capable of processing a vector of order N (say, I build it for N=12), I can use the butterfly pattern to process any vector of size M=N*2^k. That's weird I can't find any optimized kernel (for instance of order 12) for such an usage.

Comment: See "Decomposition of Binary Matrices and Fast Hadamard Transforms" (CSSP) by Hakob Sarukhanyan, Sos Agaian, Jaakko Astola, and Karen Egiazarian (not publicly available...)

Comment: Please see S.R. Webb ; J.D. Kennedy, "Some Comments on the Fast Hadamard Transform of Order Twelve", http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1671898/